# Allowed values for ALV_EXTRACT_MODE parameter with CL_SALV_EXPORT_DB_STORAGE class?

Tags: abap, alv

Where can I see the allowed value for `ALV_EXTRACT_MODE` of class `CL_SALV_EXPORT_DB_STORAGE`?

Maybe I am blind, but I could not find it with se80 and looking at the class.

Please be patient, I am new to ABAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the ABAP memory named "ALV_EXTRACT_MODE" which must be set before doing a SUBMIT ; the value "M" is to export the ALV table to the memory instead of displaying the ALV (and after the SUBMIT, you'll have to retrieve the ALV table by calling one of the IMPORT* methods of class CL_SALV_EXPORT_DB_STORAGE).

There are other values, I don't know how they work. You can find more information yourself by looking at the method SET_TABLE_FOR_FIRST_DISPLAY in class CL_GUI_ALV_GRID.

Answer (score 1):

In my NetWeaver 7.52, the class `CL_SALV_EXPORT_DB_STORAGE` doesn't have an `ALV_EXTRACT_MODE`, anywhere I suppose you relate to the `EXPORT_TYPE` instead, as e.g. seen in the method `EXPORT`.

That parameter is typed as `SALV_BS_CONSTANT` and directly forwarded to the `EXPORT` statement within the method body. Unfortunately, the language documentation doesn't mention the list of possible values either. As this `NUMC(2)` data element has no domain and hence no domain fixed values list, there is no reliable way of determining its intended values.

However, there is an interface `IF_SALV_BS_XML` with a list of constants that start with `C_TYPE_*` and that are typed as `SALV_BS_CONSTANT`, such as `C_TYPE_ALV_XML`:

```
  constants C_TYPE type SALV_BS_CONSTANT value '99' ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_PDF like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 08 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_ALV_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 01 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_EXCEL_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 04 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_XLSX like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 10 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_XLSX_DEPRECATED like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 11 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_MHTML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 02 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_MHTML_2000 like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 09 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_ODT_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 07 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_ODS_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 05 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_SO_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 03 ##NO_TEXT.
  constants C_TYPE_DATA_XML like IF_SALV_BS_XML=>C_TYPE value 06 ##NO_TEXT.
```